# IQ Puzzle with a Twist

Tags: lateral-thinking, progressive-matrix

*This my first puzzle in a very long time so if I've done something wrong let me know. I think there should be enough information to rule out wrong answers, but I don't know of a good way to verify this. This puzzle is my own creation.*

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sub>

---

Help! I was sent this IQ puzzle by a friend, and she said that I can't possibly be a genius unless I can solve it. I've been trying to solve it for hours, but I'm just really stuck. I figured, maybe all I need is a fresh pair of eyes, so I figured I'd ask all of you for help. She also said that it has a twist, and I have no idea what to make of that.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with the following figure:

> [image]

And the reason is...

> Each row presents 3 views of the same cube.
>  The cubes are transparent and you can see symbols and a line inside.
>
>  The first view in a row shows the cube from the right,
>  the second from the front, and the last from the top.
>
>  In the second row an O is hidden by an X, so there are only 3 symbols visible from the top.
>
>  Or - with a twist - the cube is rotated between the views.

PS: I first thought someone is stealing the puzzle I posted recently. :-)

Comment: Great solve! I can confirm that this is one of the ideas I had while puzzling over your holographic puzzle :)

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose there has to be the same number of objects in all 3 squares of a row. Then the empty square belongs in the middle row (red) and the square that was there goes down.

> The objects in this row go one step to the right (toric) except the green X which stays where it is.

> One O ends up on top of the green X, which is usually not allowed but which could be part of the twist.

> [image: Grid withthe result]